# Draw multiple copies of same object in opengl

Tags: c, opengl

I can't seem to understand how multiple copies of same object are being drawn using array of objects. Below you see both my draw and display methods:

```
void display()
{
    SolidSphere **spheres = createSpheres();
    float const win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(.6, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, win_aspect, 1, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        spheres[i]->draw(posX,posY,posZ);
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void draw(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &texcoords[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indices[0]);
    glPopMatrix();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

As a result I only get 1 instead of n spheres.

Comment: I cannot seem to understand how this code compiles when `n` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: n is outside both functions. Currently it's set to 4.

Comment: Ah, well it does not matter anyway. Your problem here is that you are drawing the object `n` times at the exact same position. If each object had a different color you might see some depth fighting or something, but these are all exactly the same in every conceivable way.

Comment: Could it be that the same values of posX, posY and posZ are passed, despite I use random number generator for the 3 values? Here is what I included at the header of my app:
`GLfloat posX = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 4 - 2;
GLfloat posY = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 4 - 2;
GLfloat posZ = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 5 - 10;`

Comment: You keep mentioning things that are *not* in the code in your question. Even if `posX`, `posY` and `posZ` are generated randomly they are not generated ***in*** the loop. You are looping over this `n`-many times with the same 3 values.

Comment: You were right! I generated them inside the for loop and now I've got my 4 spheres. Much thanks for your kind help!